# Android how to display song internal lyrics

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a android app that can display the song internal lyric as a music player is playing a song. I don't want to use the .lrc file. Is anyone has other option to show the song internal lyric?

Below code: Read action when music player is playing a song. I put it in onCreate().

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    // Read action when music player changed current song
    // I just try it with stock music player form android

    //Google Android player
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");        
    //HTC Music
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");      
    //MIUI Player
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
    //Real
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    //SEMC Music Player
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_TRACK_STARTED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_PAUSED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.TRACK_COMPLETED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");       
    //rdio
    filter.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.rdio.android.playstatechanged");     
    //Samsung Music Player
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");        
    //Winamp
    filter.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    //Amazon
    filter.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged"); 
    //Rhapsody
    filter.addAction("com.rhapsody.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.rhapsody.metachanged");
    //PowerAmp
    filter.addAction("com.maxmpz.audioplayer.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.maxmpz.audioplayer.metachanged");
    // MyTouch4G
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    //appollo
    filter.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
    //will be added any....

    //scrobblers detect for players (poweramp for example)
    //Last.fm
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackpaused");
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackcomplete");
    //A simple last.fm scrobbler
    filter.addAction("com.adam.aslfms.notify.playstatechanged");
    //Scrobble Droid
    filter.addAction("net.jjc1138.android.scrobbler.action.MUSIC_STATUS");


    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    //scrobbling finished
```

Here is to get the music info (mReceiver) function

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.d("mIntentReceiver.onReceive ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String lyric = intent.getStringExtra("lyric");
        String artist1 = intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST);
        String album1 = intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM);
        String track1 = intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Command : "+cmd+"\n Artist : "+artist1+"\n Album :"+album1+"\n Track : "+track1+"\n Lyric : "+lyric , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
};
```

But the lyric is showing null from this code. Is anyone has any solution?

Comment: Hi, I want to play an .lrc file and needs to show lyrics on the screen.can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer the question completely but i hope it helps to refine your problem a bit. lyric is a kind of metadata like thumbnail, the song should have the lyric metadata added if you want to display it. Make sure it is there.